# 1px shared :hover border on two elements

Tags: css, hover, border

Two `inline-block` elements next to each other.

```
.e{border:1px #ccc solid}
.e:hover{border-color:#555}
```

What I'd like is to reduce the `1px`+`1px` border between them to a shared `1px` border.

To illustrate.

```
---------
|   |   |
---------
```

Select first element.

```
+++++-----
+   +    |
+++++-----
```

Select second element.

```
-----+++++
|    +   +
-----+++++
```

It's simple to reduce the `2px` border to `1px` by setting either `border-right` or `border-left` to `0`, but how to keep the `1px` shared border when either element is selected?

Without JavaScript.

Comment: Can we see the code @pdknsk?  I think this might be a challenge without js.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could give them a -1px left margin to get their borders overlapping and then undo that margin on the first one. Then adjust the `z-index` on hover (and don't forget `position: relative` to make the `z-index` work). Something like this:

```
.e {
    border: 1px #ccc solid;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -1px;
}
.e:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.e:hover {
    border-color: #555;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/XTzqx/

You might need to play with the `:first-child` a bit depending on how your HTML is structured; a couple other options if `:first-child` or another pseudo-class won't work:

- Wrap it all in a `<div>` with `padding-left: 1px` to kludge around the `margin-left: -1px` .
- Add an extra class to the first one that has `margin-left: 0`.

Comment: Thanks, using `z-index` works great. I set `margin-left:0` directly on the element.

Comment: @pdknsk: Putting `margin-left:0` in a `style` attribute should be fine, I'd probably go with an extra class just to keep all the CSS together for easier maintenance though.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `:hover` state have a 2px border and give it `-1px margin` on both sides. Make exceptions for `:first-child` and `last-child` assuming you don't have to care about every browser out there… I'm looking at you IE6/7